# Which has a better web support ionic (react) or quasar framework?

Tags: reactjs, ionic4, quasar-framework, quasar

I am looking for a cross platform framework to build frontend with single codebase and deploy on multiple platforms.Found Ionic with react or quasar framework both seems good.

I have experience with both vue and react in building web apps but i am new to mobile app development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i think quasar has a better desktop support for its components by default.Also there are much more components in quasar framework compare to ionic react